# Non integer $\lambda$ in poisson distribuiton

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Here's the problem:

Admit that the number of phone calls received in a call center is a random variable that follows Poisson's distribution, with $\lambda$ = 30 per hour.

- Determine the probability that in the first 15 minutes the call center receives, at least, 2 calls.

What I tried:
since $\lambda$ = 30/ hour $\rightarrow$ $\lambda$ = 0,5/ minute, but by the definition $\lambda$ can only be an integer, right?

Comment: It can be non integer

Comment: I agree with @MatteoTesta ... Look up the definition of "Poisson distribution".  The number of calls in a minute is, indeed, an integer.  But it is random.  In some minutes there may be $0$ calls, in some minutes there may be $1$ call, etc.  The **expected value** of that random variable is $1/2$ calls per minute.

Comment: The average rate over a quarter-hour is $\frac{30}4=7.5$ which is fine to use

Answer (score 2):

There is no restriction that the $\lambda$ parameter of a Poisson distribution be an integer. It just represents the expected, i.e. the average, number of occurrences of an event in a given interval. Just like the average roll of a standard 6-sided die is 3.5, it's possible for the average number of calls-per-minute to be 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

The PMF of a Poisson distribution $p(n;\lambda)$ defined by the expression
$$p(n;\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^n }{n!}e^{-\lambda}$$
is a valid PMF for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda >0$. There is no restriction that $\lambda$ must be an integer. This makes intuitive sense once we realize that $\lambda$ is the expected value of such an RV. So indeed 30 calls per hour on average translates to 0.5 calls per minute or 1 per every 2 minutes. You just need to use consistent units for your computations.